# ui-router check if $state name starts with a string portion

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I thought there was a way to match if the $state name started with a pattern, but I've been googling around and I can't find the method call.

There is $state.includes('base.products'), but that seems to only match full child state names.  It won't also match 'base.product_new' if I use $state.includes('base.product')

Is there a command for $state.startsWith('base.product') ?

Answer (score 0):

Nope, that is definitely not a thing, although you could probably approximate it by poking around `$state`'s private properties.

Answer (score 0):

Currently not.
You need to write own method, which will make this work.